# Print table from hash of hash perl

Tags: perl

I have hash which will have a key 'form' and multiple keys of `Table` that point to other hashes. But tables will have any number of `tr` and `tr` will have any number of `td`. So the problem is that it is having anonymous arrays. How to print a table from this hash?

```
'form'=>{
    'Table2' => {
    'tr' => [
      {
        'td' => [
                {
                  'db_feild_name' => 'project_details',
                  'type' => 'texta',
                  'display_name' => 'Project Detail',
                  'mandate' => '1'
                },
                {
                  'db_feild_name' => 'project_name',
                  'type' => 'text',
                  'display_name' => 'Project Name',
                  'mandate' => '1'
                },
                {
                  'db_feild_name' => 'project_date',
                  'type' => 'date',
                  'display_name' => 'Date'
                }
              ]
      },
      {
        'td' => [
                {
                  'db_feild_name' => 'issue_name',
                  'type' => 'text',
                  'display_name' => 'Name',
                  'mandate' => '1'
                },
                {
                  'db_feild_name' => 'last_name',
                  'type' => 'text',
                  'display_name' => 'last Name',
                  'mandate' => '1'
                },
                {
                  'db_feild_name' => 'age',
                  'type' => 'text',
                  'display_name' => 'Age'
                }
              ]
      }
    ],
    'Table_Header' => 'test_table2',
    'Title' => 'i am table'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation:
`$table` points to,

```
{
  'tr' => [..],
  'Table_Header' => 'test_table2',
  'Title' => 'i am table'
}
```

`$tr` points to,

```
{
  'td' => [..]
},
```

and `$td` points to,

```
{
  'db_feild_name' => 'project_details',
  'type' => 'texta',
  'display_name' => 'Project Detail',
  'mandate' => '1'
},
```

Assuming your hash is `%h`

```
for my $table (values %{ $h{"form"} }) {
  # print <table>
  print $table->{"Table_Header"}, $table->{"Title"};

  for my $tr (@{ $table->{"tr"} }) {
    # print <tr>

    for my $td (values %$tr) {
      # print <td>
      print $td->{"db_feild_name"}; # type,display_name,etc
      # print </td>
    }

    # print </tr>
  }

  # print </table>
}
```